# Spark. Data caching?

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-spark, caching, apache-spark-sql

I'm testing below script in spark-shell - single partition scan of partitioned table.

```
val s = System.nanoTime

var q =
s"""
select * from partitioned_table where part_column = 'part_column_value' 
"""

spark.sql(q).show

println("Elapsed: " + (System.nanoTime-s) / 1e9 + " seconds")
```

First execution takes around 30 seconds while all subsequent executions take around 2 seconds.

If we have a look at runtime statistics - there are two additional jobs before first execution

[image]

Looks like job with 1212 stages scans all the partitions in a table (total num of partitions 1199, total num of HDFS files for this table - 1384).

I did not find a way to discover what exactly scala/java or SQL code is running for Job 0 but I suspect it's for caching.

Each time I exit spark-shell and start it again - I see this two additional jobs before first executions.
Of course, similar observations are true for other queries.

Questions

1. Is it possible to prove or negate hypothesis about caching?
2. If it's for caching - how to disable cache and how to clean it up?

**Update. Details about job.**

[image]

Comment: can you try adding the following code before the query: `spark.catalog.refreshTable("partitioned_table")` ? does it change the runtime?

Comment: lev, nothing changed.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to run `spark.sql(q).explain`. It will print the physical plan, and you could see what changes between runs

Comment: Well, obviously plans are the same. My concern is job 1 and especially job 0 which is executed before first run. The most of time is spent on job 0 which seems to be scanning all the partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was occurring for specific Spark version 2.0.2.
Spark has been scanning of all the partitions while building the plan and before query execution.

The issues has been logged and fixed in Spark 2.1.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16980